# Python: Converting list of tuples(variable size) into array like structure with fixed shape

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of tuples like:

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5)]   // np.shape = (2,)
```

And i want to covert it into an array like structure, but of fixed shape, ie

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,0)] // np.shape = (2,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [69]: maxlen=max(len(i) for i in a) #get the max length of all tuples

In [70]: [i+(0,)*(maxlen-len(i)) for i in a] #fill each tuple with extra zeros
Out[70]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Functional way to do this would be

```
a = [(1,2,3), (4,5), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
from itertools import izip_longest
print zip(*izip_longest(*a, fillvalue = 0))
# [(1, 2, 3, 0), (4, 5, 0, 0), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
```