# unable to use neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier for multilabel sparse data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, knn

I have a file having data like:

```
1,2,3 4:5 6:7................
11,12,13,14 15:16 17:18 19:20......
.
.
.
```

I have loaded this file as

```
X_train, Y_train = load_svmlight_file(filename, multilabel=True)
```

which is loading file with (for this example)

```
np.shape(X_train) = 2,3
np.shape(Y_train) = 2,    (list of tuples)
```

Then I converted `Y_train` also to sparse matrix(`csr_matrix`), and of size (2,4) for this example using answer given at [Python: Converting list of tuples(variable size) into array like structure with fixed shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114294/python-converting-list-of-tuplesvariable-size-into-array-like-structure-with)

But now when I am using:

```
 knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, weights='distance')
 knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
 y = knn.predict(X_test)    //X_test is similar to X_train only
```

It is giving following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code5.py", line 40, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "code5.py", line 36, in main
    y = knn.predict(X_test)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py", line 123, in predict
    pred_labels = self._y[neigh_ind]
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed.
```

Comment: Works fine here. Which scikit-learn version are you using?

Comment: scikit-learn version is 0.10

Comment: Then it's time to upgrade. 0.10 was released several years ago and IIRC did not support this feature at all; we're now at 0.14.